# Is there a way to call a machine code function stored in a string in perl?

Tags: perl

Using perl in MacOS, Is there a way to call a machine code
function in a string in perl?  I know this is non-portable,
and insane in most situations, but can it be done?

In C:

```
void (*foo)();      /* pointer to function returning void */
foo = "\x90\xc3";   /* nop; ret; */
*foo();             /* execute the string */
```

In perl:

```
my $str = "\x90\xc3";   # nop; ret;
&$str();  # clearly fails - but how to call the string?
```

I am not looking for suggestions to create an external
function to make the call.

I tried a text replace of SCALAR(0x) with CODE)0x) in the reference, which met with an Undefined Subroutine error since the underlying data structures still were for a string.

I tried changing the address part of a reference to a different subroutine (both a perl subroutine and an external xsub) to the address of the string with code.  That clearly had little chance since the reference needed to point to a sv instead of the subroutine code.

I considered building the sv and related data blocks in another string memory, and creating a reference pointing to them, and realized that it would still be marked as a reference to a string, and not a reference to code.

Comment: 1. That code C doesn't compile. 2. That's not a Perl sub. You could never call it as a Perl sub. To call it at all you'd need C code. 3. Don't modern OSes prevent the execution of code outside of memory pages specially marked to contain code?

Comment: 1. As another noted, the call should have been (*foo)(), but the code was not intended to compile, just to clarify the question.  To compile it, you would have to put it in a function.  2.  I never said it was a perl sub - the goal was to call this machine code, not a perl sub (the perl sub  is easy and not worth asking about). 3. Yes, some modern systems don't allow execution of some areas, but MacOS  (at least the version I am running) allows you to set the execute priv if needed.

Comment: Re "*the code was not intended to compile*", Well, you need to start by figuring that out. // Re "*you would have to put it in a function.*", duh. But it didn't compile there either.

Comment: RE "*I never said it was a perl sub*", I know. But you said you `str()` from Perl. That calls a Perl sub. And like I said, you don't have a Perl sub. And like I said, you'd need to call it from C

Answer (score 3):

Embed C code in your Perl script? `Inline::C` is one possibility.

```
use Inline C;
do_non_portable_insane_thing("hello world");

__END__
__C__

void do_non_portable_insane_thing(SV* sv)
{
    STRLEN len;
    char *ptr;
    void (*foo)();
    ptr = SvPV(sv, len);
    foo = (void *) ptr;
    fprintf(stderr, "doing the non-portable insane thing\n");
    (*foo)();
    return;
}
```

I'm not on MacOS and don't know what bytes my system might accept, so this code gives me a `Segmentation fault`, but, uh, good luck to you?

Comment: The question was how to execute this machine code from perl.  Including C code, or alternatively using the XS/XSUB mechanism to include a C function, would do it, but that doesn't help on a machine that doesn't have a C compiler.
This might be a clue in a useful direction, as it may be possible to coerce the mechanism that passes control to the C function to pass control to the address of the string instead.  And that is why I am asking - as I have not yet figured out how to do that, and hoped someone already had.

Comment: @Alan Larson, Re "*but that doesn't help on a machine that doesn't have a C compiler.*", It can be compiled on another machine and the copied over (just like what happens when you use `apt`), or you could build a DLL/SO and copy that over (and load it using FFI::Platypus)

Comment: Re "*this code gives me a Segmentation fault*" Possibly from trying to execute code found in a memory page that's not marked as executable.

Comment: @Alan Larson if your goal is to execute arbitrary machine code on a machine, I don't think Perl is the right tool for the job. Also, if you have a working Perl installed why can't you install a C compiler?